# Can I express this as a generator / coroutine?

Tags: python, generator, coroutine

Suppose I have the following class:

```
class MyGen(object):
  def next(self):
    return X()

  def send(self, x):
    return f(x)
```

Is it possible to express it as a single function, using the `yield` keyword? Suppose I have `g = MyGen()`. Note that `g.next()` shouldn't call `f()`, and `g.send(x)` shouldn't call `X()`, but `f()` and `X()` could share some code.

Comment: What is `X()` and `f()` ? or how are the two related?  How about you show us your dream code snippet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code will be almost equivalent:

```
def my_gen(x=None):
    while True:
        if x is None:
            x = yield X()
        else:
            x = yield f(x)
```

One difference is that you can't send a value (other than `None`) to a generator before calling `next()` for the first time.  Another difference is that sending `None` won't trigger calling `f()`, since the generator can't distinguish `send(None)` and `next()`.

Comment: It almost works, but... if I call g.send(x) two times, the second time it returns X() instead of f(x), because it reaches the first yield.

Comment: @Charles: Sorry, missed that.  Fixed now.  I also added the option to pass in the first `x` as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Sven's formulation is exactly the way to go, I just wanted to add that if you want to know more about generators, coroutines and such in Python, [this site](http://www.dabeaz.com/coroutines/index.html) is the place to go.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the place where I leaned about generators and coroutines. And now, I'm just doing what he tells not to do: a coroutine that returns a value!